# Different views Edit Mode vs Rendered Mode

Tags: modeling

I have this view in Edit Mode

[image]

and different view in Rendered Mode

[image]

How is it possible?

Many thanks!

I did it. Now it is better but is not circle like in Edit mode shows

[image]

I can't add the last picture..it's too large.

Comment: It looks like you've got two different materials assigned to the mesh. Select the whole mesh in *Edit Mode*, go to *Materials* panel, select one material and press *Assign* like in here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it but it is not a circle like in Edit Mode. I show you above. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have N-gons in the mesh. And they get triangulated wrong in the rendering then. That's the spikes that you see. The solution is to make those problematic N-Gons to at least quad faces.

Select those N-Gons, then use Mesh/Faces/Triangulate Faces (Ctrl + T) to make them tris. Mesh/Faces/Tris to Quads (Alt +J ) to make them quads again. Or alternatively use the knife tool to add some extra edges.